# MYSQL query for updating multiple rows base on position change of an object

Tags: mysql

I have an application which a user can create different containers which are all sortable with the JqueryUI-lib much similar to this page: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#placeholder

Upon ever sortable drag and drop I do an Ajax call for updating my DB base on the new positions of the containers so that I can show the user same order next time they return(or if they refresh the page)

My container_position table looks as followed:

```
| ID   |    UserID   | Container_name | Container_position|
|:-----|------------:|:--------------:|:-----------------:|
| 1    |      23     |  ItemA         |        0          |
| 2    |      23     |  ItemB         |        1          |
| 3    |      23     |  ItemC         |        2          |
| 4    |      23     |  ItemD         |        3          |
| 5    |      23     |  ItemE         |        4          |
```

The question is how can I write a MYSQL query so that it updates all the Users container position base on the movement of one.?

Assume the user moves itemE to Second position (position 1) this should make the position of  ItemA=0 (unchanged) , ItemB=3, ItemC=4, ItemD=5

Right now I’m doing this with a Loop in PHP but I’m hoping to find a more efficient way to do this in MYSQL

Thank you for your help.

Comment: My advice: Don't bother updating them all since it almost certainly has to happen in a loop. Instead drop them all in one statement, then insert them all back in their new positions in a second statement.

Comment: What's wrong with updating only the ones that need to update? If itemE takes on position 1, increment the positions of all containers having position >= 1 for that UserID.

Answer (score 3):

This operation can be done in a single SQL statement.

To move a single element in the list "up" (a lower value of `Container_position`), for example moving item in position 4 to position 1, you could use this expression to derive new values for the column:

```
IF(cp >= 1 AND cp < 4, cp+1, IF(cp = 4 ,1 ,cp))
```

To move a single element "down" (a higher value for `Container_position`), for example moving item in position 3 to position 5, you could use this expression:

```
IF(cp <= 5 AND cp > 3, cp-1, IF(cp = 3, 5, cp))
```

To make the expression more readable, I abbreviated the column_name to `cp`.

If you wanted to generalize that into a prepared statement using bind variables 
(`:np` is value of the new position and `:op` is value of the old position), just do a simple test to determine whether it's moving "up" or "down":

```
UPDATE container_position_table t
SET t.cp = IF(:np < :op,
           IF(t.cp >= :np AND t.cp < :op, t.cp+1, IF(t.cp = :op, :np, t.cp)),
           IF(t.cp <= :np AND t.cp > :op, t.cp-1, IF(t.cp = :op, :np, t.cp)))
WHERE t.cp BETWEEN LEAST(:np,:op) AND GREATEST(:np,:op)
```

(Obviously, you would need to replace `cp` with the actual name of the column.)

[SQL Fiddle demonstation here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4a80/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4a80/1)

---

That first expression is MySQL shorthand for the equivalent SQL-92 compliant expression:

```
CASE WHEN cp >= 1 AND cp < 4 THEN cp+1
 ELSE CASE WHEN cp = 4 THEN 1 ELSE cp END
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with 3 queries:

1. Increment the position of the items after the new position and before the old position of the moved item:

   ```
   UPDATE container_position SET container_position = container_position + 1 WHERE container_position >= $new_position AND container_position < $old_position
   ```
2. Decrement the position of the items after the old position of the moved item:

   ```
   UPDATE container_position SET container_position = container_position - 1 WHERE container_position > $old_position
   ```
3. Set the new position of the current_item:

   ```
   UPDATE container_position SET container_position = $new_position WHERE ID = $moved_item_id
   ```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you transfer from position 1 to 0.