# Re-arrange position in a table maitaining order

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following table:

| id | todo_id | type | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | boolean | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | dropdown | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | dropdown | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | text | 3 |
| 5 | 1 | dropdown | 4 |

Let's say I move `id - 2` to `first position` then I would have the following table:

| id | todo_id | type | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | dropdown | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | boolean | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | dropdown | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | text | 3 |
| 5 | 1 | dropdown | 4 |

I have done the following in Laravel:

```php
protected function updatePositionSubTodos(int $oldPosition, int $newPosition, SubTodo $subTodo): void
{
    // `byTodo` is just a scope that adds `where todo_id = ?` to the query
    SubTodo::byTodo($subTodo->todo_id)
    ->where('position', '>=', $newPosition)
    ->where('position', '<', $oldPosition)
    ->update([
        'position' => DB::raw('sub_todos.position + 1')
    ]);

    SubTodo::byTodo($subTodo->todo_id)
    ->where('position', '>', $oldPosition)
    ->update([
        'position' => DB::raw('sub_todos.position - 1')
    ]);

    SubTodo::byTodo($subTodo->todo_id)
    ->where('id', $subTodo->id)
    ->update(['position' => $newPosition]);
}
```

but when I make a request to the endpoint that uses this function (service) the following happens:

| id | todo_id | type | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | dropdown | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | boolean | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | dropdown | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | text | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | dropdown | 3 |

I have two `1` in the `position`. This algorithm is from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17903033/4581336. How can I update the `position` field while maintaining the a sequential order? Please, consider that all permutations can happen (an item can go up or an item can go down in the position)

Comment: Maybe the order in which you execute the updates has to be changed. Have you already tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the approach on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17903033/4581336) is that it fails to take into consideration that you can move the items into the first, last, and in a negative position.

## Moving to the first position - index 0

A visual example that can be used is having the following array:

```
// for the sake of it let's consider this a 0 indexed array
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If I would like to move `2` to the first position (array index 0), then after removing the `2` from the array I would end up with:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Since I would like to keep an ordered array I have to do:

1. Increment the values that are lower than the `oldPosition`
2. Move the item to the first position
3. update its position to `0`

```
// incrementing the values to the left aka lower than `oldPosition`
[1, 2, 3, 4]

// move the item to the first position
[2, 1, 2, 3, 4]

// update the item to reflect position `0`
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

For this we can write the following PHP method:

```php
private function processMoveToFirstPosition(SubTodo $subTodo, int $oldPosition)
{
    SubTodo::byTodo($subTodo->todo_id)
       ->where('position', '<', $oldPosition)
       ->update(['position' => DB::raw('sub_todos.position + 1')]);

    $subTodo->update(['position' => 0]);
}
```

## Moving to the last position

A visual example that can be used is having the following array:

```
// again, assuming array is zero index
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If I would love to move `2` to the last position, then after removing the `2` from the array I would end up with:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Since I would like to keep the same ordering then I have to do:

1. Decrement the values from the `oldPosition`
2. Move the item to the last position
3. update its position to `$numberItems`

```
// decrementing the values to the right aka higher than `oldPosition`
[0, 1, 2, 3]

// move the item to the last position
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2]

// update the item to reflect position `$numberItems`
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

For this, we can write the following PHP function

```php
private function processToLastPosition(SubTodo $subTodo, int $oldPosition)
{
  SubTodo::byTodo($subTodo->todo_id)
    ->where('position', '>', $oldPosition)
    ->update(['position' => DB::raw('sub_todos.position - 1')]);

  $subTodo->update(['position' => SubTodo::byTodo($subTodo->todo_id)->count()]);
}
```

## Updating to positions in the middle of the array

Now let's assume that we would like to move `3` to position `1` of the array (index 1)

```
// removing the number 3 from array
[0, 1, 2, 4]

// add the `3` into position `1`
[0, 3, 1, 2, 4]
```

Now we have an array that looks random but now we just need to look in the values between `newPosition` (position that it will be moved to - `1`) and the `oldPosition` (position that the elemnt was at - `3`). If the element moved to a lower position, we should increment the values between. If the element moved to a higher position, we should  decrement the values.

```
// removed element from position 3 to 1
[0, 1, 2, 4]
    |  |
    |  |
  Increment these values
  because we moved from a higher
  position to a lower one

// after increment we would end up with
[0, 2, 3, 4]

// now we can insert element `3` into position `1`
[0, 3, 2, 3, 4]

// now we update element `3` to become `1`
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now let's try the inverse. Move from a lower position into a higher position

```
// removed element 1 to position 3
[0, 2, 3, 4]
    |  |
    |  |
   these values should be decremented
   because we moved from a lower position
   into a higher position

// after decrementing it would end up with
[0, 1, 2, 4]

// now we can insert element `1` into position `3`
[0, 1, 2, 1, 4]

// now we update element `1` to become `3`
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

For this last part we can write the following code:

```php
private function move(SubTodo $subTodo, int $newPosition, int $oldPosition)
{
    $start = min($newPosition, $oldPosition);
    $end = max($newPosition, $oldPosition);
    $operator = $newPosition > $oldPosition ? '-' : '+';

    SubTodo::byTodo($subTodo->todo_id)
       ->where('position', '>=', $start)
       ->where('position', '<=', $end)
       ->where('id', '!=', $subTodo->id)
       ->update(['position' => DB::raw('sub_todos.position ' . $operator . ' 1')]);

    SubTodo::byTodo($subTodo->todo_id)
       ->where('id', $subTodo->id)
       ->update(['position' => $newPosition]);
}
```

## Putting all together

Now that we have covered three edge cases that can happen we can write the following code:

```php
protected function updatePositionSubTodos(int $oldPosition, int $newPosition, SubTodo $subTodo): void
{
    $totalNumberSubTodos = SubTodo::byTodo($subTodo->todo_id)->count();

    if ($newPosition === 0) {
        $this->processMoveToFirstPosition($subTodo, $oldPosition);
    } else if ($newPosition >= $totalNumberSubTodos) {
       $this->processToLastPosition($subTodo, $oldPosition);
    } else {
       $this->move($subTodo, $newPosition, $oldPosition);
    }
}
```